# C++ destructor called timing for returned value

Tags: c++, return, return-value, destructor

Consider C++ code as below:

```cpp
struct V {
  int s;
  V(int s): s(s) {}
  ~V() { cout << "Destructor\n"; }
};

V f() {
  V x(2);
  return x;
}

int main(){
  V a = f();
  cout << "Function End\n";
  return 0;
}
```

The execution result shows that the destructor is called only once.

```
Function End
Destructor
```

However, if I add a meaningless if statement as below, the destructor is called twice.

```cpp
V f() {
  if(false) return V(3);
  V x(2);
  return x;
}
```

```
Destructor
Function End
Destructor
```

Why can this happen? Is there some points to avoid calling destructor twice?

Comment: Print the value of `this`, not just the word "Destructor".  Then you will see you are destroying another object (which you are not tracking).

Comment: You might get a better picture of what is happening if you added some noisey constructors.

Comment: Also have a look at RVO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the destructor being called twice? That shouldn't normally matter to you.

Comment: I originally wrote a class which dynamically allocated memory instead of `V` and I had a problem of double free. I thought this problem is caused by the destructor being called twice. Now I figured out the reason for double free is the inappropriate copy constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example, [NRVO](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) (*Named Return Value Optimization*) may kick in and elide the copy in `return x;`.

When you have two exit paths, not returning the same variable, NRVO is less likely to kick in and you'll actually get a copy, even though `if(false)` is never going to be `true`.

The below would most likely also elide the copy because `x` is returned in all paths that leads to `return`.

```cpp
V f() {
    V x(2);
    if (false) x = V(3);
    return x;
}
```